# Getting error "method findViewByID(int) is undefined" while following developer.android.com tutorial

Tags: android, methods, undefined, android-edittext

I've just started learning android programming and have started the online tutorial at developer.android.com.  Have been following step by step and checking code, but now getting an error and can't proceed.

On the line:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.edit_message);
```

I'm getting the error "The method findViewByID(int) is undefined for the type MainActivity"

The code seems to be identical to what is shown on the website, so not sure what I'm doing wrong.  Any help appreciated.  Entire code below:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

/** Called when the user clicks the send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // do something in response to button
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `findViewById(..)`, not `findViewByID(...)`. Java is case sensitive.